# Template parameter as parameter of other template

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a Matrix class. It's a template with type, rows and cols for static allocation of small matrix. The problem is with the overload of operator* and operator*=. In this case the operation must be granted for a different object: same type, rows equals to my column and a number of columns. I wrote this code now and it works, but I wonder if I can force to use the same type T instead of having another type T1. Same thing for rows and columns.

```
template<typename T, int R, int C>
class Matrix {
 private:
   //some data.....
 public:
   //some methods.....
  template <typename T1, int R1, int C1> <----here I'd like to use T as type
  Matrix<T,R,C1> operator*(const Matrix<T,R1,C1>& rhs);
  template <typename T1, int R1, int C1>
  Matrix<T,R,C1>& operator*=(const Matrix<T,R1,C1>& rhs);
}
```

Comment: My advice: Make both op* and op*= free functions. (You need to constrain your rhs for op*= to a square matrix of the proper dimension) Also, you have too many degrees of freedom for your op*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `operator *`, the template parameters don't have to match the function arguments, so you can just leave it out.  Also, there is a restriction that the number of rows of the second matrix match the number of columns of the first matrix, so you really only need one template parameter:

```
template<typename T, int R, int C>
class Matrix {
 private:
   //some data.....
 public:
   //some methods.....
  template <int C1>
  Matrix<T,R,C1> operator*(const Matrix<T,C,C1>& rhs) const;
};
```

`operator *=` can only work with square matrices, so you have to be careful there.

Comment: Remember it's a matrix-class, and that is matrix-multiplication: The template operator is too templated.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T, int R, int C>
class Matrix {
 private:
   //some data.....
 public:
   //some methods.....
  template <int C2>
  Matrix<T,R,C2> operator*(const Matrix<T,C,C2>& rhs);
  Matrix& operator*=(const Matrix<T,C,C>& rhs);
}
```

You can just use the template arguments from the enclosing class, no worry.

Anyway, I reduced both operators to what matrix-multiplication actually allows.